# Vase and marginal probability

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a vase with different balls as follows:

- $15$ blue (B)
- $12$ red (R)
- $10$ green (G)
- $5$ white (W)

The probability to see a **blue** ball in the **1st pick** and a **green** ball in the **3rd pick** would be the marginal (without replacement: once one color is picked, all balls of that color are out of the vase):

$
P(B*G*) = P(BRGW)+P(BWGR)=
\big ( \dfrac{15}{42} \times \dfrac{12}{27} \times \dfrac{10}{15} \times \dfrac{5}{5} \big )
+
\big ( \dfrac{15}{42} \times \dfrac{5}{27} \times \dfrac{10}{22} \times \dfrac{12}{12} \big )
$

I have two questions:

1. Is there any other way to compute $P(B*G*)$ (I mean without computing the marginals)?
2. Can we claim that $\dfrac{P(B*G*)}{P(G*B*)} > \dfrac{P(R*G*)}{P(G*R*)}?$ The intuition behind is that the number of blue balls compared to green balls is higher than that of red and green balls.

Thanks for any help or hint.

Comment: What about possible $BRGR$ output?

Comment: Replacement is putting a ball back to the vase, so that you can draw the same _ball_ again. But I'm talking about drawing _another_ ball in the same _color_ – you have $12$ red balls in a vase, so you can draw two red balls even without replacement.

Comment: That is a problem completely different from what you presented above. You didn't say about removing non-picked balls from the vase! Please post _precise_ descriptions of your problems.

Comment: I included that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about the colors picked in the first and in the third draw, so you don't have to bother about the fourth one. You need, however, to consider the case with the second ball being green and the case of second ball being non-green.

First, from all possible triplets we can separate those starting with **blue**.
The probability of picking a blue ball in the first attempt is
$$P(B) = \frac{15}{15+12+10+5}=\frac{15}{42}$$

In the second attempt we pick from $41$ remaining balls with $10$ green among them, so we can either pick a **green** ball with conditional probability
$$P(*G|B) = \frac{10}{41}$$
or a **non-green** ball with probability
$$P(*\overline G|B) = \frac{41-10}{41}=\frac{31}{41}$$

If the second ball picked was green, we're left with $9$ green balls in the vase, so the probability of picking a **green** ball as a third one from remaining $40$ is
$$P(**G|BG)=\frac 9{40}$$
and in the opposite case
$$P(**G|B\overline G)=\frac{10}{40}$$

Finally the probability of drawing a three-ball sequence with the first ball blue and the third one green is
$$P(B*G) = P(BGG)+P(B\overline GG)\\
= P(B)\cdot P(*G|B) \cdot P(**G|BG) + P(B)\cdot P(*\overline G|B) \cdot P(**G|B\overline G) \\
= \frac{15}{42} \cdot \frac{10}{41} \cdot \frac 9{40} + \frac{15}{42} \cdot \frac{31}{41} \cdot \frac{10}{40} \\
= \frac{6000}{68880} \\
= \frac 1{11.48} \approx 0.087108$$

Comment: +1 for your attempt, not what I'm looking for, though.